# VBA ExportAsFixedFormat only saving last active chart

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to save a single worksheet from a workbook as a pdf using the ExportAsFixedFormat method:

```
    Sheets("Overview").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=Mid(saveFile, 1, InStr(saveFile, ".")) & "pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

This worked for a while until i started doing some chart manipulation beforehand. The manipulation I am talking about looks like this:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 4").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Measurements").Range( _
    "C4:C29,G4:G29")
```

Now its not exporting the whole sheet as a pdf but rather only the chart called "Diagramm 4".
I more or less understand why it's doing this but I can't find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try selecting any cell on that sheet  like:

```
Range("A1").Select
```

before you export the page. Likely this is happening because you're making the chart active without making it inactive again. Look what happens when you normally select a chart and then try to print a worksheet - it'll just try to print the chart.